# ==21==ERROR: AddressSanitizer failed to allocate 0xdfff0001000 (15392894357504) bytes at address 2008fff7000 (errno: 12) ==22==ReserveShadowMemoryRang

Tags: c++

I dont know why i am getting this error whenever i am returning any string .
Link:- https://leetcode.com/contest/weekly-contest-349/problems/lexicographically-smallest-string-after-substring-operation/
Error Shown:-
==22==ERROR: AddressSanitizer failed to allocate 0xdfff0001000 (15392894357504) bytes at address 2008fff7000 (errno: 12)
==22==ReserveShadowMemoryRange failed while trying to map 0xdfff0001000 bytes. Perhaps you're using ulimit -v

When i am returing any string whether it may be correct or not ,it should not give error message

Comment: Please provide the code you are running to get this error. Secondly, the `dsa` tag has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered today the same error. But after a while (10-15 minutes), my code was successfully submitted without any changes.

Apparently, the error is due to temporary issue on the LeetCode server side.

The error stems from the [AddressSanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer), which is a tool for detecting memory errors. The issue here is related to "shadow memory" of AddressSanitizer, which is evident from the "ReserveShadowMemoryRange" in the error message. One of purposes of using shadow memory is to check if memory has been appropriately freed in certain areas. And shadow memory is an extra memory, in addition to what your c++ code uses. So there was not enough memory for that.

From [Github discussion](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/1467) it seems for me that the issue could be due to disabled overcommit policy of the virtual machine where your code is executed at the side of LeetCode's servers. Overcommit allows to allocate more memory than physically available. But its just blind guess.

Try running your code again after some time, the error should disappear. If problem persists, reach out to LeetCode's support team to notify them of this issue.

Comment: Yeah, same think happened with me today, never found this issue earlier